# How does performance of SQL Server CE and SQL Server Express compare?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-compact

We have an application that runs on netbooks. It currently uses a SQL Server CE 3.5 database, and we are thinking of upgrading to SQL Server Express.

Just wonder if there are any benchmarks to compare the performance of SQL Server CE and SQL Server Express? Would it be too intensive for an atom netbook?

We are using SQL Server CE 3.5 and we are thinking of moving to SQL Server Express 2012.

UPDATE:
Why are we wanting to upgrade? Because we will now be using merge replication with the SQL Server Express database.

Also we don't want to limit ourselves. We might use stored procedures and triggers on the database because with the replication solution we will be redesigning parts of our system.

Comment: I'd be much more concerned about app/code/schema compatibility. Are you upgrading because CE is slow, or some other reason(s)?

Comment: I'll update the question because there are a number of reasons for upgrading.

Comment: The problem with expecting benchmarks is that nobody else has an app like yours. I'm afraid the best guess you're going to get is to make the conversion and test the app yourself. Even someone who has gone through this process will likely have a different enough application with different enough performance characteristics that you shouldn't be basing business decisions on them. IMHO.

Comment: Sure but I am just trying to gauge whether this is a good idea to pursue, or whether there would or could be any major performance roadblocks, and I don't mean performance roadblocks caused by our application.

Comment: In the context I meant, app also = schema and database code.

Comment: I'm going to agree with @AaronBertrand.  The only way to truly know in your environment and with your implementation is to set it up side-by-side and test.  It's just conjecture without doing otherwise. (Unless, of course, somebody has had the same requirement and can give tried-and-true results.  But even then, I'd still test test test)

Comment: *Would it be too intensive for an atom netbook?* YES

Comment: What is your justification for saying that Remus? We have been running SQL CE on our netbooks for a long time, and based on our software currently I have no reason to believe SQL express wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your case and reasons to upgrade

[merge replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172367%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) is available in SQL Server CE 3.5

Stored procedures, views, triggers is not available in SQL Server CE 3.5

for a basic comparison between the 2 editions in your case working on a net book

1.
SQL Server CE 3.5 can Runs as in-process with application
SQL Server Express runs as a service

2.
SQL CE supports maximum size of 4GB
SQL Express can go up to 10GB

3.
SQL CE Doesn't Support FILESTREAM
SQL Express Supports FILESTREAM

4. Procedural T-SQL - Select Case, If, features is not supported in SQL CE
   Procedural T-SQL - Select Case, If, features is supported in SQL Express

5.
Distributed transactions is not supported in SQL CE but supported in SQL express

6. Native XML, XQuery/XPath is not supported in SQL CE but supported in SQL express

7.
Stored procedures, views, triggers is not supported in SQL CE but supported in SQL express

8. Role-based security is not supported in SQL CE but supported in SQL express

9.
concurrent connections supported in SQL CE is limited to 100 but unlimited in sql express

this is a [useful blog](http://erikej.blogspot.com/) focused on sql CE

for the comparison between the 2 in your specific environment you can use these tools

[SQL LOAD TEST](http://sqlloadtest.codeplex.com/)
[SQL STRESS TEST TOOL](http://www.sqlstress.com/Walkthrough.aspx)

and check this post on SO about sql statment performance
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555471/what-tools-are-available-to-test-sql-statement-performance